# Generating configuration for an EC2 instance using Amazon AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have an existing EC2 instance myEC2 up and running.
How do I use the  CLI to generate the configuration for this so that I can run a command in my CLI window that will create a new identical EC2 with the name myEC2_B?
Amazon documentation is a disaster as far as I can see.  Seems to assume a certain level of knowledge for every topic

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about how to do this from the command line interface, but it's certainly possible (and quite easy, I might add):

1. Jump over to [your Instances page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home#Instances:).
2. Find and select the instance that you want to duplicate:

   [image]
3. Under the **actions** menu, click **create image**

   [image]
4. Give the image a name, etc. in the dialog. If you are in a dev environment and can shutdown the server, you should probably tick the **no reboot** box. Otherwise, leave it unticked. Wait while it's created.
5. Head over to the **AMIs** option in the sidebar:

   [image]
6. Find your newly-created image and tick it:

   [image]
7. Click the big blue **launch** button at the top of the screen. You'll get to choose an instance size, etc.

   [image]
8. Enjoy your duplicated server ;)

Comment: With CLI:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is the CLI I want to use.  This manual way is how we currently do it but we want to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do at least a two step process, but lets look at how we would do it all from the console.

1. list our instances along with their name and instance id:

   > ```
   > aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=* --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress,InstanceId,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]]' --output text | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /'
   > ```

I get a nice spit out of my instances, IP and instance ID along with the name, take note of the instance we want and its instance-id
[image]

2. Now we are going to write that Instance to a new ami using the create-image ec2 sub command:

   > ```
   > aws ec2 create-image --instance-id="MYINSTANCEID"
   > ```

[image]

Now we have the AMI (image-id) we simply launch new ec2 instance with the ami id like so:

> ```
> aws ec2 run-instances --image-id="ami-d13513b2" --key-name="jjs-skyramp" --security-group-ids="sg-daa5c5bf" --instance-type="t2.small"
> ```

Of course if you did this all too quickly you will get the following:

[image]

Which is telling us the AMI we created before is still pending, so might want to wait till thats finished, and I assure you the command will copy your Imaged machine :)

You can see the commands I used, what I used represents the bare minimum to launch an image as a new ec2 instance, you can see all the other options at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

Its easy to get your id's for each appropriate paramater by simply running:

> ```
> "aws ec2 describe-THING-I-WANT-TO-SEE
> ```
>
> then play some with filters for the json data.

Hope this helps.